# Armadillo matrix-Vector Multiplication Error

Tags: c++, gcc, matrix, vector, armadillo

I want to run a simple matrix-vector multiplication in C++, but it give me error.
This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main() {
mat B(5, 10, fill::randu);
mat C(10, 5, fill::randu);
mat U = B * C;
return 0;
}
```

This is the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA4Cqsm.o: in function `TLS wrapper function for arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance':
main.cpp:(.text._ZTWN4arma23arma_rng_cxx11_instanceE[_ZTWN4arma23arma_rng_cxx11_instanceE]+0x25): undefined reference to `arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA4Cqsm.o: in function `void arma::blas::gemv<double>(char const*, int const*, int const*, double const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, double*, int const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma4blas4gemvIdEEvPKcPKiS5_PKT_S8_S5_S8_S5_S8_PS6_S5_[_ZN4arma4blas4gemvIdEEvPKcPKiS5_PKT_S8_S5_S8_S5_S8_PS6_S5_]+0x57): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dgemv_'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA4Cqsm.o: in function `void arma::blas::gemm<double>(char const*, char const*, int const*, int const*, int const*, double const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, double*, int const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma4blas4gemmIdEEvPKcS3_PKiS5_S5_PKT_S8_S5_S8_S5_S8_PS6_S5_[_ZN4arma4blas4gemmIdEEvPKcS3_PKiS5_S5_PKT_S8_S5_S8_S5_S8_PS6_S5_]+0x63): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dgemm_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Did you compile with `-larmadillo`? Also `using namespace std;` along with doing same with other  namespaces in global scope is a recipe for ill-formed program or unintended behaviour.

Comment: How did you install armadillo? Armadillo can be used either as a header only library or you can compile a wrapper library. From your error it seems you are trying to use it as a wrapper library, but you didn't link to it property. You might prefer to use it as a header library and directly link with blas and lapack instead.